# Not getting refresh token even though access_type is offline and prompt=consent

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

i'm using this link to access
[https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope='.urlencode($google_oAuth_scope).'&redirect_uri='.$redirect.'&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=code&client_id='.$client_id."&access_type=offline&prompt=consent"](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=%27.urlencode($google_oAuth_scope).%27&redirect_uri=%27.$redirect.%27&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=code&client_id=%27.$client_id.%22&access_type=offline&prompt=consent%22)

but this not return a refresh token after the authorization

i read google documentation